# Google Realtime API - What is my Application ID?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Looking at [sample here](https://github.com/googledrive/realtime-playground/blob/master/js/rtpg.js#L31)

```
 /** Your Application ID from the Google APIs Console. */
 rtpg.APP_ID = YOUR_APP_ID;
```

I'm looking at Google API Console, I see Client ID and API key, but I can't find a field with my application id. Is it actually marked as Application ID or is it something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In APIs Console, go to "Overview" menu and you will find "Project Number". That is App id. I will ask for update of the documentation.

Comment: holy *swear words* does that need renaming haha.